# Get local file paths to place in img tags in html

Tags: javascript, html, file, local

I'm building a HTML page that should display all the images in a certain local folder. The number of files in this folder depends on users dropping images into it, so the number of files are never the same.

So far I'm not able to read the files in the local folder and add them as img tags in HTML. My goal is to make sure I don't have to keep adding the images by hand.

Is this possible with HTML5 or javascript?

Comment: Are the images numbered sequentially? If not, you can't do this without a server-side component

Comment: Yes, they are numbered sequentially.